# Can't create an instance on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to create an instance on GCE with `gcloud`, I get the error below.

```
gcloud compute instances create --zone us-west1-a tunnel

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
- The zone 'projects/project/zones/us-west1-a' does not have enough
resources available to fulfill the request.
Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

In the Google Cloud Console Platform the zone is displayed available. I also tried to create an instance within the Platform without success.

[image: google compute engine zones available]

Answer (score 2):

First, our apologies that you’re experiencing this issue. Be assured that the team is working hard to resolve it.

Our goal is to make sure that there are available resources in all zones. This type of issue is rare. When a situation like this occurs, or is about to occur, our team is notified immediately and the issue is investigated.

We recommend deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage. Please review our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.

I recommend you to try to create your instance in a different zone or try later as this is in most of the cases a transient error and it should not last for too long.

I also recommend you to take a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) with instructions to distribute your instances across zones so you can increase availability. This [other link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems) is also useful as you will find best practices for designing robust systems on GCE (Google Compute Engine).

Comment: Still face the issue today and I have the same error for every zone. I'm not able to create any instance.

Comment: Have you tried creating instances in a completely different region? europe-west4, for example? Would you receive the same error? Or is the issue related specifically to us-west1 ?

Comment: Yes I tried completely different regions too. I could create an instance around 9 hours ago, but yet I get the error again.

Comment: Is this issue still ongoing for you?

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried all solutions here without any success.

Comment: It's happening on a daily basis for instances with GPUs on us-central1-a. I've created an issue on Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168225740

Answer (score 0):

To "fix" this, just create VM without **external IP**, then after VM success created edit and add a external IP.

Comment: Not working for me. Further, I have an existing instance but can't start it anymore. I get the same error as in the creation.

Comment: @MichaelMeister If you already created a VM, just edit and remove external IP, then start VM and after start edit and add external IP again.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating new instances with dynamic ip, there is none with fixed ip, even though I can not acidify a new one.

Comment: I could create one for zone us-west-1 right now. Maybe you have luck in this timeframe as well.